# How can I get data from TableLayout and then parse it to int[][] array?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to develop simple matrix calculator.

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            EditText cell = new EditText(this);
            cell.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            row.addView(cell);
        }
        table.addView(row);
    }
```

This is how I create a `TableLayout` for entering matrix elements, but I don't know how to get its values and parse them to `int[][]` array for further calculations.

I tried to do like these

```
TableLayout table = new TableLayout(this);
        EditText[][] cells = new EditText[size][size];
        TextView matrix = new TextView(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                cells[i][j] = new EditText(this);
                cells[i][j].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
                row.addView(cells[i][j]);
            }
            table.addView(row);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(cells[i][j].getText().toString());
                matrix.append(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            matrix.append("\n");
        }
        table.addView(matrix);
        setContentView(table);
```

But I get an exception. I know why I'm getting it, but i don't know how to avoid it

Stack trace:

```
03-19 17:16:59.366 3610-3610/com.example.matrixtest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.example.matrixtest, PID: 3610
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.matrixtest/com.example.matrixtest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
      at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
      at com.example.matrixtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
03-19 17:17:02.059 3610-3610/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3610 SIG: 9
```

Comment: It's a very broad question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your message. I stated what I tried. I know, that I will get an exception, because nothing was entered, but how can I wait for matrix to be filled?

Comment: If you get an exception, please post the full stack trace so we know what went wrong.

Comment: Looks like you have to decide what you want to do when a cell doesn't contain a valid number.  You'll have to catch NumberFormatException and make the decision there.

Comment: But I don't even have time to enter it. That is a problem. I don't know how to let user enter values, and then after user entered them, parse them to int[][] for further calculations